# d3js onClick function can't access variable from superordinate function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, d3.js, global-variables

I seem to not really understand when a function can access outside/global variable and when not. As far as I understand it, a variable that is defined outside of a function can be used inside the function because to it the variable is global...

However that doesn't seem to apply - or I'm making a stupid mistake again.

I have an array of objects "knotenListe[ ]". I use a for-loop to call a function to draw a circle for each object. As parameters I use the object itself "knotenHandle" and the index of the current object in the knotenListe[ ] array as "arrayPosition":

```
function zeichneKnoten (knotenHandle,arrayPosition) {
    console.log("Function called. Parameter arrayPosition=" + arrayPosition);
    kreisListe[arrayPosition] = svg.append("circle")
        .style("stroke", "white")
        .style("fill", "grey")
        .attr("r", 20)
        .attr("cx", knotenHandle.positionX)
        .attr("cy", knotenHandle.positionY)
        .attr("id", knotenHandle.name)
        .on("click", function(){
            console.log("onClick triggered. arrayPosition=" + arrayPosition);
            doStuff(arrayPosition);
        });
}
```

I have two console.log statements to check the value of arrayPosition. The first one works just fine, but the second one in the .on("click" segment returns "undefined".

What am I missing? The function in the .on("click" segment is subordinate to the zeichneKnoten function, correct? And I can access arrayPosition within the zeichneKnoten function just fine. Is this some general hierarchy thing I misunderstand about JavaScript variables/functions or is this maybe something special to the d3.js library I'm using to draw the circles?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what's happening here is, by the time you `click` on the `circle`, the `arrayPosition` is becoming `undefined`. Try using a self invoked function.

```
function zeichneKnoten (knotenHandle,arrayPosition) {
    console.log("Function called. Parameter arrayPosition=" + arrayPosition);
    kreisListe[arrayPosition] = svg.append("circle")
        .style("stroke", "white")
        .style("fill", "grey")
        .attr("r", 20)
        .attr("cx", knotenHandle.positionX)
        .attr("cy", knotenHandle.positionY)
        .attr("id", knotenHandle.name)
        .on("click", function(position){
            return function(){ 
               console.log("onClick triggered. arrayPosition=" + position);
               doStuff(position);
            }
        }(arrayPosition));
}
```

**Explanation:**
I am using javascript closures to the advantage here. On Click function doesn't get executed until the circle is clicked. By the time someone clicks on the circle the value of arrayPosition is becoming undefined. Now, as you see, when assigning the function to the onclick event of the circle, we are self-invoking the function which in turn return another function. Outer function is executed as soon as the `.on("click",...)` is executed. This means, when the outer function returns the inner function, it will have a closure for `position` variable, which contains the value of `arrayPosition`. So even if arrayPosition becomes undefined, we don't care as each circle will have it's own function assignment with it's own `arrayPosition` value stored inside `position` closure.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work! However I must admit that I don't know why/how exactly. I don't quite understand your construction with that return function(). Could you please try and explain step by step how it works?

Comment: Added some explanation. Please accept the answer if you think this is what you needed.